# C# VS uninstaller 2010- application shortcut

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, shortcut

I have created vs installer 2010. all works fine. I even created the shortcut and it works fine too. User's Desktop -> Create Shortcut to User's Desktop. The problem is it only creates a short cut to the application folder and not to the application it self (ie abc.exe). how can I create a short cut to the application? also I notice that after the install the shortcut link on the desktop does not show right away. I have to fresh F5 (refresh my desktop) for the icon to show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select **Application Folder**, right click on **Primary Output from <YourProject>** and then select **Create shortcut to primary output from <YourProject>**.
Then drag the shortcut and drop it on the **User's Desktop** folder.

Comment: is this vs2010? when I select application folder and right click I only see: Add, Create Shortcut to application folder, cut (greyed out), paste, delete, properties window. I don't see Primary Output.

Comment: Yes, it's VS 2010. Is your application folder empty? What do you see in the right panel when you select it?

Comment: not empty. I have my programs there (exe, dll, config files,etc)

Comment: and I add them (my programs) by doing this: application folder->add->file

Comment: Right click on your exe file and select "Create shortcut to ...", then drag that shortcut to the user desktop folder.